# htaccess wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Всем добрый день ,нужно помощь первый раз сталкиваюсь с такой проблемой
У меня на WP имеется страница:
http://mysite.ru/blog/?category=news
После равно может быть ещё много других названий
Проблема заключается в том что нужно чтобы выводилось в адресной строке
http://mysite.ru/blog/news
Но при этом оставался на этой же странице просто надо скрыть '?category='
Кто знает можете подсказать,буду очень благодарен.

Файл htacces выглядит следующим образом:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cat/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog?category=$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/blog/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog?category=$1 [R=301,L]


# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]


# END WordPress
```

Comment: Такой СТРАНИЦЫ в ВП быть не может. https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B А ЧПУ настраивается в админке.

Comment: Если вы про ?category=, то это я сделал для вывода категорий, а если полностью про всю ссылку, что я сомневаюсь то конечно вместо mysite.ru другое содердимое

Comment: Я и про структуру урла (`blog/?category=news`) и про типы контента. Ссылку что, зря давал? А ещё  добавлю что у станиц нет РУБРИК (а не "категорий". их и подавно нет). Хотя через кастомную таксономию и можно соорудить. Только не нужно. Ибо страницы не для этого.

Answer (score 0):

Настройки -> Постоянные ссылки -> Пункт: Произвольно и указать свой вариант, к примеру:
`/%category%/%postname%/`

Comment: Через постоянные ссылки выводит на файл arhive.php,а мне надо работать в файле blog.php и  arhive.php категории не подгружаются

Comment: @АндрейДёмин изучаем матчасть https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2